# How to use AQtime (free) in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, aqtime

Embarcadero says that I got some free version of AQtime when I purchased my Delphi XE license. However, today I tried to run for the first time AQtime and I got an error message: 'You are using AQTime Standard... Line-level profiling can be performed in AQTime Pro only' and then it says to upgrade to Pro.

I see only an 'Abort' and a 'Help' button. When I click the Help button is says "This program cannot display the webpage". Once I press the 'Abort' button... well... you can imagine what happens :)

I would have upgraded without bothering to ask this question if the upgrade would have been below 70-80 dollars. But when I looked one AQTime web site I have seen that it is almost as expensive as my Delphi license!

So, there is any free version of AQTime included in Delphi? If yes, what am I doing wrong? How do I make it work? If not, there is a way to remove the AQTime plugin from IDE? I could at least make the IDE load faster this way.

Comment: Looks like the AQTime update fixed your problem? 
Usual location: http://cc.embarcadero.com/reg/delphi

Comment: Thanks a lot Warren for your link! I am downloading those 86MB right now.

Comment: I cannot make it run. I will just install a different product or wait until I have to reinstall Delphi XE (probably soon knowing how unstable Delphi is) and see if it works after reinstall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right - the Standard edition of AQtime has some features missing. In your case, the missing feature you are trying to use is the line-level profiling - the thing that shows you links to specific code lines in the profiling results. The Standard edition can profile only on the Routine level - you will see routine names in the results and the call stacks (where appropriate), but without line numbers. You can lear more about the differences here:

http://smartbear.com/products/development-tools/performance-profiling/standard-for-rad-studio-vs-pro/

So, to actually use AQtime Standard, open the Setup page and configure the profiling areas to be Routine-level. You can read more about this here:

http://smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/17718/

http://smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/17895/

The docs are for the standalone Pro version of AQtime (not integrated to the IDE), but the UI and the functionality is very similar, so you should be able to sort things out.

Comment: There should be a bug in Delphi or AQTime because even if under 'Full Check By Routines' the 'by Routines' is checked instead of 'by Lines', I still get that 'Upgrade now' message.

Comment: When this message is displayed, it should mention the cause. What is the exact text? Also: What profiler are you using (main menu "AQtime | Current Profiler")? Can you post a screen shot of the Areas panel? And what AQtime version is this (Help | About Embarcadero RAD Studio | Installed Products)?

Comment: I want to use Performance Profiler (it was active by default). Ver is 7.0.307. Its the default version that came with Delphi XE/Update 1. The message is the one posted in my original question.

Comment: Hmmm... I've just tried with this version and it works. A screen shot of the Areas panel would be great. Can you post it somewhere and paste the link here?

Comment: Hi Alex. I will wait to see if the link provided by Warren will fix the issue.

Comment: BTW, regarding the non-working Help button in the dialog: do you have the RAD Studio Help system installed? If it's not installed, you will get this problem - AQtime Help integrates to the RAD Studio Help, and if the latter is not present, the former will not integrate anywhere.

Comment: How things are going with the new version?